# List<T>.Remove() how will work on exact same objects

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry if very primitive question but I am not sure how does this works with List, when you call `Remove()` method and pass to it an object, that in the collection an object with totally same fields and values does already exist.

I have a class like this:

```
public class Test
{
    private List<string> _names;

    public void Add(string name)
    {
        _names.Add(name);
    }

   public void Remove(string name)
   {
        _names.Remove(name)
   }
}
```

What happens if more than same one (instance) of `name` are in the list already? Considering calling this Remove method from another class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx).

It says for `.Remove(T item)`:

"Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the `List<T>`."

If you want to remove all occurences, use `.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)`, like so:

```
public void Remove(String name) {
    _names.RemoveAll( s => s.Equals( name ) );
}
```

Comment: First occurrence? So it does nothing with reference?

Comment: Items in a `List<T>` are referenced by index, not by value. The "first occurence" would be the lowest index value where `value.Equals(item)` returns true. The fact that the same value exists at another index later in the list is irrelevant because it will still be at that location (well, shifted up because the `.Remove` operation will move items along).